# multiline table header using knitr and latex

Tags: r, latex, knitr, tables-package

I ended up using `tables` package with `knitr`, but I can not figure out how to get a multiline header. Here is the code:

```
<<test_table, results='asis', echo=FALSE>>=
matrix <- matrix(1:9, nrow = 3)
colnames(matrix) <- c("first column", "seconf column which I want to have 2     lines because of its very long header title", "third column")
library(tables)
table <- as.tabular(matrix)
latex(table)
@
```

Comment: Can you simply add \n, as in "seconf column which I want to have 2\nlines...?

Comment: Did it work for you @lawyeR? For me "\n"is simply ignored.

Comment: @dariaa, you are right.  Doesn't seem to work (I also tried a simple carriage return and tried the setNames() function.  I'm no Latex guru but have you looked at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39253/multiline-table-header

Comment: See also [grouped headers](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/kableExtra/vignettes/awesome_table_in_html.html#Grouped_Columns__Rows) i.e. "tables with multi-row headers" in the kable extra package, in case that is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

It's probably possible to do this with the `tables` package, but `xtable` provides a very easy solution. The following minimal example shows two different approaches:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

<<setup, echo = FALSE>>=
library(xtable)
library(knitr)
opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE, results = "asis")

matrix <- matrix(1:9, nrow = 3)
  colnames(matrix) <- c(
    "first column",
    "second column which I want to have 2 lines because of its very long header title",
    "third column")
@

<<ChangeColumnType>>=
  print(xtable(matrix, align = c("r", "r", "p{4cm}", "r")), include.rownames = FALSE)
@

<<ChangeOnlyCell>>=
  colnames(matrix)[2] <- "\\multicolumn{1}{p{4cm}}{second column which I want to have 2 lines because of its very long header title}"
  print(xtable(matrix), include.rownames = FALSE, sanitize.colnames.function = identity)
@
\end{document}
```

The first approach (chunk `ChangeColumnType`) is very simple: It sets the column type of column 2 to `p{4cm}`. That gives a column that is 4cm wide with automatic text wrapping (see [wikibooks.org](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Tables#The_tabular_environment) for more details). The drawback is, that this affects the whole column, not only the cell in the first row.

The second approach (chunk `ChangeOnlyCell`) uses default alignment (or whatever you want to specify via `align`) and changes only the column type of the problematic cell using `\multcolumn`.
By default, `xtable` "sanitizes" your table, meaning that all special latex characters will be escaped. This is handy because you cannot (easily) break your TEX code, but here we manually want to inject LaTeX code, so we have to turn this off. Therefore, set `sanitize.colnames.function = identiy`. All column names will be used as you specify them – so be careful when using characters with a special meaning in LaTeX.

The example from above delivers the following tables:
[image: Result]